# excluding some tags from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I searched the web but I could not find proper answer for my question.
I am using below code to change English numbers to Persian.
but the code changed whole body numbers and i need apikey td to be excluded, any idea?

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("[lang='fa']").find("*").andSelf().contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
      this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\d/g, function(v) {
        return String.fromCharCode(v.charCodeAt(0) + 0x06C0);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div lang="fa">

    <div>some text here and 1234567890</div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="apikey">123qwe456qwe123</td>
        <td id="apikey">456ert456</td>
      </tr>

    </table>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDs need to be unique.

Use a class and the [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) or [:not](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("[lang='fa']").find("*").andSelf().not(".apikey").contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
      this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\d/g, function(v) {
        return String.fromCharCode(v.charCodeAt(0) + 0x06C0);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div lang="fa">

    <div>some text here and 1234567890</div>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="apikey">123qwe456qwe123</td>
        <td class="apikey">456ert456</td>
      </tr>

    </table>


  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks mplungjan, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Only change the things you want to change. give the elements the changeLanguage class like i gave to the div. give this class to any element you want to change.

```js
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$("[lang='fa']").find("*").not(".dontChangeLanguage").contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) 
{
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/\d/g, function(v) {
            return String.fromCharCode(v.charCodeAt(0) + 0x06C0);
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div lang="fa">

<div class="changeLanguage">some text here and 1234567890</div>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="dontChangeLanguage" id="apikey">123qwe456qwe123</td>
<td class="dontChangeLanguage" id="apikey">456ert456</td>
</tr>

</table>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Sameer, but i need whole body to change except <td id="apikey"> yout code only changes selected div

Comment: there are many divs to change and i cannot give all of them ChangeLanguage class

Comment: Answer updated with Not. give the elements a class which you dont want to change

Comment: Now the same as mine